# Find Xcode SDK files on OS X Mavericks

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm searching for the SDK files of Xcode. I tried everything, searched in ~\Library\Developer and so on. I can't find them. I installed Xcode. Where can I find the SDK files on my Mac?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Folder -> /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer

SDK is now in the XCode.app